# Нужно ли тире как усиление?

Tags: пунктуация

*Гидре самостроев — конец.* Нужно ли тире?

Comment: Я в этом не очень силён, но как авторский знак точно можно. Сталкивался с подобными фразами с тире.

Answer (score 2):

***Гидре самостроев — конец.***

Тире объясняется просто: оно заменяет отсутствующую часть выражения ПРИШЁЛ КОНЕЦ.

В предложении тире очень уместно, да и интонационно фраза выигрывает тоже благодаря тире.

Answer (score 0):

**Гидре самостроев — конец!**

Предложение эллиптического типа (дополнение –  подлежащее), пауза обозначается тире.   Еще можно восклицательный знак поставить, по структуре предложение похоже на лозунг.

Answer (score 0):

Польза тире здесь зависит от того, какой смысл вы вкладываете в предложение. Если речь о неизбежном конце, прогнозируемом по каким-то признакам его приближения, то оно не нужно (ср. "Они уже рядом. Нам конец."), хотя и возможно - в зависимости от тональности, степени неравнодушия к надвигающемуся (беспокоит эта "гидра" или невольное наблюдение за ней из окна вызывает ленивое презрение). Если же речь о свершившемся и желанном, то тире можно обосновать как обозначающее восклицание по поводу прекращения безобразия или как замещение опущенного, но подразумеваемого сказуемого "наступил(-таки)". В этом смысле знак "авторский", он факультативен.